# C++ API Design Patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have an API implemementation / design question to ask. I need to design a modern, usable DLL API, but I am unsure which approach is best and why. I'm not even sure if what I have below could be considered either!

My implementation of the classes needs to be abstracted from the client, but the client also needs to be able to extend and define additional (supported) classes as needed. Many of the internal classes of the library will need references to these external components, necessating the use of *pure virtual* classes or polymorphism.

I'm not too worried about GNU/Clang compatability - that may come later (as in **much later** or possibly *never*) but the primary need is in the ABI layers of MSVC 15/17.

The two ways *I can see* to implement this is to either use to use a `Pimpl` idiom or an external `Factory` method. I'm not a big fan of either (PIMPL adds to code complexity and maintainability, Factory abstracts class creation) so a well thought out third option is a possibility if viable.

For the sake of the simplicity in this post, I've put the "implementations" in the headers below, but they would in their own respective CPPs. I've also cut out any implied constructors, destructors or includes.

I'll define two pure virtual classes here for the meantime

```
//! IFoo.h

class IFoo
{
    virtual void someAction() noexcept = 0;
}
```

```
//! IBar.h

class IBar
{
public:
    virtual void Foo(IFoo& other) noexcept = 0;
};
```

Edit, I'll put this here too:

```
//! BarImpl.h (Internal)

class BarImpl : public IBar
{
public:
    virtual void Foo(IFoo& foo) noexcept
    {
        foo.someAction();
    }
};
```

> First up, we have the PIMPL approach

```
//! Bar.h (External)

class API_EXPORT Bar : public IBar
{
private:
    BarImpl* impl;

public:
    virtual void Foo(IFoo& foo) noexcept
    {
        impl->Foo(foo);
    }
};
```

Ideally, the client code therefore looks alittle something like this:

```
//! client_code.cpp
class CustomFoo : public IFoo;

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto foo = CustomFoo();
    auto bar = Bar();
    bar.Foo(foo); // do a barrel roll
}
```

> Secondly, we have a Factory approach

```
//! BarFactory.h (External)

class API_EXPORT BarFactory
{
private:
    BarImpl impl;

public:
    virtual IBar& Allocate() noexcept
    {
        return impl; // For simplicity
    }
}
```

The resulting client code looking something like:

```
//! client_code.cpp
class CustomFoo : public IFoo;

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto foo = CustomFoo();
    auto barfactory = BarFactory();
    IBar& bar = barfactory.Allocate();
    bar.Foo(foo); // do a barrel roll
}
```

In my eyes, both approaches have their own merits. The PIMPL method, although double abstracted and possibly slower due to all the virtualisation, brings a humble simplicity to the client code. The factory avoids this but necessitates a seperate object creation / management class. As these are external functions, I don't think I can easily get away with templating these functions as you might expect to with an internal class, so all this extra code will have to be written either way.

Both methods seem to ensure that the interface remains stable between versions - ensuring binary compatibility between future minor releases.

Would anyone be able to lend a hand to the conundrum I have created for myself above? It would be much appreciated!

Many Thanks,
*Chris*

Comment: your factories only ever create a single object. Not sure but I never heard this being called a "factory"

Comment: I don't see how the factory approach helps in this case. When designing public APIs, easy of use and documentation are key. Asking the user to implement an interface does both.

Comment: The idea of the factory here is aide in hiding the true implementation from the client, in addition to adding the ability to create multiple classes from a single point in the API - without it you would be presenting _BarImpl_ to the client. I've noticed another typo above, I'll correct it

Comment: looks like you could just have a static IBar::create() function that returns a pointer to a new object. if you don't have multiple impls of Bar (which you seem to be suggesting you won't) then why make it more complex than it needs to be?

Comment: A few of the classes do share the same (in this case virtual) base class, but this isn't the case with all of them. I'll admit I hadn't thought of adding a static function due to trying to keep the virtual classes "clean", but I could do something along that approach. I suspect part of my issue here is trying to apply one pattern to all of the classes that I need in the API, rather than assessing them on a case-by-case basis. This wasn't out of laziness, rather to keep consistency across the API

Comment: You are reinventing COM